# Javascript multi event listener to one function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a scoreboard in HTML and JS, and I'm wondering is there anyway I can add 2 or 3 event listener to one function for different button?

My first thought is using switch statement like:

```js
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", score);
document.getElementById("2").addEventListener("click", score);
document.getElementById("3").addEventListener("click", score);
function score() {
  switch(button.id) {
    case "1":
      ...
    case "2":
      ...
      
    ...
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work, can someone help me ?

thanks.

Comment: You need to define `button` in your score function. E.G, it could be `function score(evt) { let button = evt.target;}` or even just `this`.

Comment: it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delegate the event to the parent container(Event delegation). You can retrieve the information by adding a data attribute to the elements

```js
function score(evt) {
  var index = evt.target.getAttribute('data-index');
  if (index) {
    console.log('You clicked on: ' + index);
  }
}

document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].addEventListener("click", score);
```

```css
.container div{
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div data-index="1">1</div>
  <div data-index="2">2</div>
  <div data-index="3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

html

```
<input type="button" id="b1" onclick="score(this.id)">
<input type="button" id="b2" onclick="score(this.id)">
<input type="button" id="b3" onclick="score(this.id)">
```

JS

```
function score(x)
{
  //your code
}
```

This should work.